# PATH not working even after successfully modifying it

Tags: environment-variables, executable, bashrc, paths

For some reason I am successful in adding new directories to my `$PATH` but when I run the commands in the terminal the `$PATH` doesn't summon them.

I modified the `$PATH` in the `~/.bashrc` file, and added the last directory

```
# Set the default system $PATH:
PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/games:**/home/aldin/mybin/fasta-35.4.12/bin**"
```

But when I run the command it says `command not found`. However when I type the full path of the utility I'm able to run it.

Has anyone experienced this problem before? Do you know what I can do to fix this problem?

Comment: `.bashrc` is the wrong file, you should change `PATH` in `.profile`. See [Alternative to .bashrc](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/alternative-to-bashrc/3085#3085). Nonetheless, changing `.bashrc` should work when you launch applications from that terminal. Are you running a shell other than bash? Is your `.bashrc` read? Tell us what `ps $$` shows in a terminal. If you add the line `set -x` at the top of `.bashrc`, what output do you see when you open a terminal?

Comment: I think that you will get what you want entering `export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/aldin/mybin/fasta-35.4.12/bin`. I hope that some user confirm or refute this information.

Answer (score 5):

First, make sure that you're restarting your session.  Either by closing the terminal window, or logging completely out and back in.

Next, make sure you have actually modified the `PATH` with `echo $PATH`.

If you're not the `aldin` from the file's path (or even if you are), make sure you have permissions to see that directory and to execute that file.

Finally, make sure the command you are trying to run is actually marked with the execute permission. Something like `chmod a+x /home/aldin/mybin/fasta-35.4.12/bin/file.sh` should work.

Also, you are trying to modify the `PATH` in a very dangerous way. Instead try:

```
PATH="$PATH:$HOME/mybin/fasta-35.4.12/bin/"
```

**NEVER** (sometimes I wish there was a "super bold") modify the `$PATH` the way you are, always reference the current `$PATH` in there somewhere or you will overwrite, rather than, append to the existing entries in it.

Comment: Gilles is also correct if your not running bash .bashrc won't do much good.

Comment: Aldo is modifying `.bashrc`, not `.profile`, so he doesn't need to log out and back in, only start a new terminal. The permissions on the files are ok, otherwise he woulnd't be able to execute the command with the full path.

Comment: @Gilles "logging in and out of your session".. may have been poorly phrased, but the point is, a new session is needed, either by closing and opening terminal, running bash by hand, or some other way. I will edit the answer. -- leaving log out and back in instead of assuming X.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same type of problem. I couldn't get bash to accept a library path so that my program could use it. That's when I found out about the linker manager.
Linux has a linker manager named **ldconfig**. I navigated to */etc/ld.so.conf.d* as a root user. Then I made a config file in there named something like **myLibPaths.conf**. I added one library path line to that file: like; */home/userName/lib*. You could probably add as many path lines to that file as needed. After that, a configuration command was needed.

Execute **ldconfig** on the command line. Verify the path addition with *ldconfig -v | less **or**  ldconfig -v | grep /home/userName/lib*.

&)To delete the paths:
***rm** /etc/ld.so.conf.d/myLibPaths.conf*

&)To edit the paths:
Edit **myLibPaths.conf** then run **ldconfig** again.

I have not experimented with setting a library path using bash any more. I may have been able to set the library path with *LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PATH:$HOME/lib*, but the linker manager works just fine. The whole trouble was in getting bash to acknowledge the **LD_LIBRARY_PATH**. Perhaps Linux doesn't handle libraries in this way at all?